# Glossaries jump page in twocolumn document

Tags: glossaries, supertabular

I am getting a strange behavior with `glossaries` package. If a place a large number of entries while using a `twocolumn` document, sometimes I get underfull columns with the glossary jumping inexplicably to the next page. I know that I can avoid it using a different glossaries style, but the idea is having a fancy aligned list of entries. Following you can find a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,nogroupskip]{glossaries}
\makeglossary

\begin{document}
\title{Minimal working example of glossaries in twocolumn document using \texttt{super} style and a long list of entries spanning in more than one page and more than one column}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{abstract}

\foreach \n in {1,...,30}{\newglossaryentry{x\n}{name=var, description=Dummy entry with a long description}}

\glsaddall
\printglossary[title=Nomenclature,style=super]

\section{More text}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Any news here? Does the answer solves your question? If yes you could accept and vote ...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the problem stems from the `supertabular` environment determining that there isn't sufficient space in the column, which triggers a page break. The effect can be reproduced without the `glossaries` package. This is essentially what the `glossaries` package is doing behind the scenes:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[debugshow]{supertabular}

\begin{document}
\title{Minimal working example of glossaries in twocolumn document using \texttt{super} style and a long list of entries spanning in more than one page and more than one column}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{abstract}

\section*{Nomenclature}
\begin{supertabular}{lp{.6\hsize}}
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
\end{supertabular}

\section{More text}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

I've used the `debugshow` option, which makes `supertabular` write extra information to the log file. This information starts with:

```
Package supertabular: Starting a new supertabular on input line 16.


Package supertabular: Average line height: 13.0pt on input line 16.


Package supertabular: Stretched line height: 1.0pt on input line 16.


Package supertabular: Calculating height of tabular on first page on input line
 16.


Package supertabular: Height of text = 388.97215pt; 
(supertabular)        Height of page = 384.26657pt on input line 16.


Package supertabular: two column mode on input line 16.


Package supertabular: First column on input line 16.


Package supertabular: Second column on input line 16.


Package supertabular: Available height: -4.70558pt on input line 16.

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 16.

Package supertabular: Height of head: 2.5pt on input line 16.


Package supertabular: Height of tail: 15.5pt on input line 16.


Package supertabular: Maximum height of tabular: -4.70558pt on input line 16.


Package supertabular: Minimum height of tabular: 31.0pt on input line 16.


Package supertabular: starting new page on input line 16.
```

It seems to be the section header that's throwing the calculations. However, if a page break is forced immediately before the section header, then the tabulated content fits:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[debugshow]{supertabular}

\begin{document}
\title{Minimal working example of glossaries in twocolumn document using \texttt{super} style and a long list of entries spanning in more than one page and more than one column}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{abstract}

\pagebreak
\section*{Nomenclature}

\begin{supertabular}{lp{.6\hsize}}
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
var & Dummy entry with a long description\\
\end{supertabular}

\section{More text}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

So it seems to be some kind of odd feature of `supertabular`. The same patch works with your MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\foreach \n in {1,...,30}{\newglossaryentry{x\n}{name=var, description=Dummy entry with a long description}}

\begin{document}
\title{Minimal working example of glossaries in twocolumn document using \texttt{super} style and a long list of entries spanning in more than one page and more than one column}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{abstract}

\glsaddall
\pagebreak
\printglossary[title=Nomenclature,style=super]

\section{More text}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image: image of page 1]

This is a bit of a kludge. I know you don't want to change style, but there is an alternative style that produces a `tabular`-like result without actually using a `tabular`-like environment, which you might want to consider. For example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\foreach \n in {1,...,30}{\newglossaryentry{x\n}{name=var, description={Dummy entry with a long description, and some more padding}}}

\glsaddall
\glsfindwidesttoplevelname
\renewcommand*{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\title{Minimal working example of glossaries in twocolumn document using \texttt{super} style and a long list of entries spanning in more than one page and more than one column}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{abstract}

\printglossary[title=Nomenclature,style=alttree]

\section{More text}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image: image of page 1]

The available width for the name is computed using `\glsfindwidesttoplevelname`. Alternatively, you can set the widest value using `\glssetwidest`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\foreach \n in {1,...,30}{\newglossaryentry{x\n}{name=var, description={Dummy entry with a long description, and some more padding}}}

\glsaddall
\glssetwidest{XXXXXX}
\renewcommand*{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\title{Minimal working example of glossaries in twocolumn document using \texttt{super} style and a long list of entries spanning in more than one page and more than one column}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{abstract}

\printglossary[title=Nomenclature,style=alttree]

\section{More text}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image: image of page 1]

The MWE only has the same short `name`. The style is demonstrated more clearly with the entries from the `example-glossaries-long.tex` test file (provided with the `glossaries` package).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-long}

\glsaddall
\glsfindwidesttoplevelname
\renewcommand*{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\title{Minimal working example of glossaries in twocolumn document using \texttt{super} style and a long list of entries spanning in more than one page and more than one column}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{abstract}

\printglossary[title=Nomenclature,style=alttree]

\section{More text}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image: image page 1]

Unlike the `tabular` styles, this allows a line break mid-description, which may or may not be appropriate for you.